# Question related to continuity in Topology ( A proof i am unable to understand)

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I am self studying Topology from C.Wayne patty and I am unable to think about a step in proof of a theorem in Section 1.6 .

Adding image ->[image]

Note that i have question in only (c) ->(d) part of the proof.

> In that part I am unable to understand how in 2-3rd line assuming x to be limit point of $f^{-1}(B)$ implies f(x) $\epsilon$ closure of $ f(f^{-1}(B)) $ .

I tried using definationof a limit point but it's not clear to me.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the step that actually uses the hypothesis (c). In (c) take $A$ to be $f^{-1}[B]$; we’re assuming that $p\in\operatorname{cl}A$, so by (c) we have $f(p)\in\operatorname{cl}f[A]=\operatorname{cl}f\big[f^{-1}[B]\big]$.

Comment: A similar question I have but I don't think it should be asked as seperate question -> Let C be a closed subset of ( Y, U) . Does the statement that closure of $f^{-1}(C) $  is a subset of $f^{-1} (C) $ implies that $f^{-1} (C) $ is a closed subset of (X, T) ? Please help.

Comment: @User: Remember that for any set $A$ in any topological space, $A\subseteq\operatorname{cl}A$. Thus, if we also have $\operatorname{cl}A\subseteq A$, we can conclude that $A=\operatorname{cl}A$ and is therefore a closed set.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @User: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Begin with an open nbhd of $f(x)$ in $Y$, $U$ say.  Since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(U)$ is an open nbhd of $x$ in $X$.  Since $x$ is a limit point of $f^{-1}(B)$, there is $x_0$ in $f^{-1}(U)$ which is also in $f^{-1}(B)$.  Clearly $f(x_0)$ is in U and also in $f(f^{-1}(B))$.  So $f(x) \in \overline{f(f^{-1}(B))}$.

Comment: Prof. Santos' answer is better.